# QUECTEL EC21 GSM module how to receive data wihtout sending a query?

Tags: algorithm, webserver, quectel, gsmcomm

I can communicate with a web server over HTTP functions like get and post with no problem.

The algoritm works like this;

- I send a query with get
- Than start to listen
- If any data received, I read it.

I need to if I didnt send any request to server, how could I receive the data?

Because server starts the communication, and after the beginning I'm directing it.( send to server, and listen the response ...)
The problem is server can send a request to start communication once a day, or once a week, or more.

In addition there may be many client such as me...

And if server wants to start communication, I have to reply quickly. ( just in seconds...)

How should I setup the algoritm?